# What is a relationship between Volumetric Analysis and Titration Theory?

Tags: titration

I believe that Volumetric Analysis and Tetration Theory are not the same subject.
But I need to know what is a main difference between those subjects and what is a main intersection?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean [titration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titration), not “tetration”. “Volumetric analysis” is another (somewhat dated) name for titration, as explained the first paragraph of the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titration).